# Fetch value of a cell based on dropdown menu items results on another sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup, google-finance

I have 2 Sheets named as Sheet1 and Sheet2...

**Sheet1:** Contains Drop down list on B4 Column. Based on the selection of an item, it pulls the result of the open price shown on D4 column.

**Sheet2:** Contains 2 Columns.
Based on Column 1 Id It needs to get the open price from Sheet 1 and should be shown in column 2 of Sheet 2...

**Note:** I don't want to modify sheet1 and 2 in any way... Please don't add any additional column in sheet1 and 2...Using that I can achieve the result...

Without modifying any criteria I need to get the result cause I will be retrieving past data and will do some complex operations on that...

link [Sheets](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16VHuO1_PhpA8czAX1dB4Nblu45xpmPI2qJsi2MYqG7g/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

paste in **B2** cell on **Sheet2**:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A, Sheet1!B4:D4, 3, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: I know that..I don't want to do this way...Cause I will be fetching historical data and applying some complex formulaes and finding results.. For that case I need excatly the same implementation..

Comment: can you provide an example of the desired output?

Comment: The same output you shown in above image...But need to fetch from another sheet's drop down results...And I don't want to add a new column and fetch results based on symbol in neither sheets...I just want to fetch from drop down results..

Comment: @RahulReddy answer updated